# Is the following function measurable?

Tags: real-analysis

If $c_1,c_2,s$ are positive.
Is the following function $f(x)$ measurable?
$$\left( \frac{2c_1(1+s x^{-1})+c_2}{1+s x^{-1} } \right)$$

#### Context

I am trying to use it in the probability generating function theorem in  [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118186/have-i-used-the-probability-generating-function-of-poisson-point-process-correct). For some reason after I perform the integration I get a divergent integral, and I don't understand why, so I thought maybe the problem is the function itself is not measurable.

Comment: What difficulty are you having with this exercise? The arithmetic operations on measurable functions preserve the measurability; if you don't have this fact at your disposal, proving it is a better way to proceed than dealing with each specific formula that you encounter.

Comment: thanks, I am trying to use it in the probability generating function theorem, please check my other question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118186/have-i-used-the-probability-generating-function-of-poisson-point-process-correct, for some reason after I perform the integration I get a divergent integral... and I don't understand why, so I thought maybe the problem is the function itself is not measurable...